# I can't use inherited class instead of mother class in generics

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi suppose this following simple class:

```
public class CRUDController<T extends __Entity<T>> {
 ...
}
```

And

```
public class Tag extends __Entity<Tag> {
...
}
```

And

```
public class KalaTag extends Tag {
...
}
```

When I use `public class TestController extends CRUDController<Tag>` everything is ok but when I use `public class TestController extends CRUDController<KalaTag>` the following error appears:

> Type parameter 'KalaTag' is not within its bound; should extend '__Entity < KalaTag >'

- What is my problem?
- What did I wrong?

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: @zlakad is it really matter to use this identifier? My question is about inheritance and generics not about naming

Comment: Of course it isn't really matter, but I couldn't resist myself - my brain is working in the other (maybe wrong) way. No needs for hard feelings ;)

Answer (score 3):

`CRUDController` expects its argument (`T`) to extend `__Entity<T>`.

Clearly `KalaTag` does not do it, as it extends `__Entity<Tag>`.

---

Possible solutions:

1. Make `KalaTag` extend `__Entity<KalaTag>` directly
2. Define `Tag` as `class Tag<T> extends __Entity<T>` and then `class KalaTag extends Tag<KalaTag>`

Answer (score 2):

Another options is to allow `CRUDController` to work with any `__Entity` bound by parent type of `T`.

```
public class CRUDController<T extends __Entity<? super T> > {
}
```

Again this really depends on your usage of `T` in `CRUDController` and its subclasses.